# Eccentric of clean deadlift form

Tags: deadlifts

During concentric, the deadlift is similar to a squat concentric followed by an RDL concentric movement. When it comes to heavier loads, it seems so the RDL eccentric directly leads me the barbell to land nearer to my heels. I don't feel any pain from this.

Is this correct form? Else, how can I learn to drop my hips from doing the eccentric?

[Video reference](https://youtube.com/shorts/IOcRIhvdjRY?si=HcP3aVU4NaHon8RM)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the bar down is just the reverse of going up. You want it to go straight down.  In your video, your knees come forward as you lower the bar. You can see the bar has to go around your kneecaps as it passes by. Apart from potentially hitting your knees, swinging the bar forward like that can make your round your lower back and hurt yourself.